# SearchPlus plugin configuration

Tags: search, javascript, plugin-searchplus

How can you change from instant search and faceting to a search bar with auto-completion? [SearchPlus](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/searchplus) comes with an excellent sample template but this is set to instant search, which means all entries in the index are displayed. I want to have a search-bar only and when typing the search query the relevant entries start to appear (auto-completion).

Also, if there is no excerpt field available in the indexed entries, would it be possible to create one, with Twig split?

```
{% set paragraphs = entry.body|split('</p>') %}
{% set firstParagraph = paragraphs|first ~ '</p>' %}

{{ firstParagraph|raw }}
```

Answer (score 2):

See this tutorial by Algolia for autocomplete search: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/auto-complete/

You would use Search Plus only to keep your index in sync with your sections